# Show / hide base on input file value

Tags: jquery

I have got an input file

```
 <input type="file" name="image" id="file">
```

and a button that save this file

```
 <input type="submit" value="Upload / Edit picture" name="upload_picture" id="upload_picture" class="btn" />
```

I need a JavaScript that will hide button if file was not choosen = 0, else show button if file choosen.

Comment: Just as a design question: wouldn't it be better to disable the submit button rather than hiding it? I think a non-displayed submit button can still be submitted by pressing <enter> or the likes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="file" name="image" id="file">

 <input type="submit" value="Upload / Edit picture" name="upload_picture" id="upload_picture" class="btn" />

<script>
$(function(){
   $("#upload_picture").hide();
   $("#file").change(function(){
        if ($("#file").val() != ""){
             $("#upload_picture").show();
        }
        else{
             $("#upload_picture").hide();
        }
   });
});
</script>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/6d8cd.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#file').change(function(){
    $('#upload_picture').show();
});
```

and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xGAVj/

Comment: This will not exactly work out as expected. In some corner cases this could cause the submit button to show while you just emptied the input field.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input id="fld" type="file" name="image" id="file">

<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Upload / Edit picture" name="upload_picture" id="upload_picture" class="btn" />
```

Javascript:

```
$("#fld").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() != "")
      {
           $("#btn").toggle();
      } else{
           $("#btn").toggle();
      }
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/saDFC/

Comment: Thank you for example and life preview !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#file").change(function(){
  if(!$(this).val()){  
      $("#upload_picture").hide();
  }
  else{
      $("#upload_picture").show();
  }
});
```